# How t add data in separate columns data in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

question:

```py
goldmedal = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['india', 'japan', 'korea'],
                         'Medals': [5, 3, 4]}
                    )

silvermedal = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['india', 'china', 'korea'],
                        'Medals': [9, 0, 6]}
                    )

bronzemedal = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['japan', 'india', 'vietnam'],
                        'Medals': [4, 2, 2]}
                    )
```

I need to find the cumulative medals earned by the mentioned countries.

I tried this

1. add function: `goldmedal.add(silvermedal, fill_value=0)` O/P

```
       Country  Medals
0      indiaindia      14
1      japanchina      3
2      koreakorea      10
```

2. merge function: `pd.merge (goldmedal,silvermedal, how='inner', on='Country')`
   O/P

```
           Country      Medalsx   Medalsy
    0      india          5         9
    1      korea          4         6
```

How do I get the following output?

```
       Country  Medals
0      india      16
1      china      0
2      korea      10
3      vietnam    2
4      japan      7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat([goldmedal, silvermedal, bronzemedal]).groupby('Country').sum().reset_index()
```